# TableCell ImageView Set Image With URL: SDWebImage: Only resizing first row

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview, sdwebimage

Inside my method I have the following code.

It works great on the fist table row record, however the remaining cells don't get resized.

**HOWEVER**, when I start scrolling, they do. I can't seem to figure out why. Is there something more I need to be doing?

```
[cell.imageView sd_setImageWithURL:url
                  placeholderImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"default.png"]
                         completed:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error, SDImageCacheType cacheType, NSURL *imageURL) {

                          if (image) {

                              NSLog(@"%@", account);

                              CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(32, 32);
                              UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
                              CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
                              [image drawInRect:imageRect];
                              cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
                              UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
                              cell.imageView.layer.cornerRadius = 16;
                              cell.imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;
                          }
    }];
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem.
The completed block of SDWebImage does not run on the UI thread and hence ui updates do not make it to the screen.

Adding the following in the completion block solved it for me:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
  [cell setNeedsLayout];
});
```

E.g. it is necessary to dispatch a request for relayout of the cell to the ui thread.